# Why does the code work fine on jsfiddle but not on my dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi I am new to JS so I am using Jsfiddle as a trial. However, when I copy the code from Jsfiddle (it works in JSfiddle) "http://jsfiddle.net/yzLbh/190/" and paste it into my dreamweaver it doesnt work. This is just part of my code that doesnt work and I took out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
               $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
               $(".message").keyup(function(){
                  var chars=$(this).val().length;

                  $("#spanner").text(140-chars);

                  if(chars > 140 || chars <=0){
                            $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
                            $("#spanner").addClass("minus");

                  }else{
                    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#spanner").removeClass("minus");
                  }
               });
           });
     </script>

</head>

<body>

           <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="tagboard" class="form" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('name','','R','message','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
<p>
<label for="name" class="labelname"></label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="(Required) Name"/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="message" class="labelmessage"></label>
<textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" class="message" maxlength="140" placeholder="(Required) Message"></textarea>
</p>
 <span id="spanner"> 140 </span> Characters Remaining

<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="tagboard" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add the jQuery library to your code in dreamweaver?

Comment: Hi like I mentioned im new to this. So is this the jQuery library code? "<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add  a `<script>` tag that includes `jquery.js`. Here's a version using Googles' CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you put that before the `script` tag containing your own code.